# How to count arithmetic expression like: '10+2-4/2'

Tags: c

I have the little problem with my program. I need sum the arithmetic expression like e.g.: 10+2+1/2, using only recursion.

I wrote something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int calculate(const char* expr, float *result);
int calculate_rec(const char* expr, float *result, int i, char sg, int number);

int main(void){
  char expression[201]={0};
  char *expr=expression;
  float result;
  float *res=&result;
  printf("enter operation: ");
  fgets(expr, 201, stdin);
  fflush(stdin);

  calculate(expr, res);
  printf("%.2f", result);

  return 0;
}

int calculate(const char* expr, float *result){
   if(expr==NULL) return 0;
   calculate_rec(expr, result, 0, 0, 0);

  return 1;
}

int calculate_rec(const char* expr, float *result, int i, char sg, int number){
  if(isdigit(*(expr+i))) number=number*10+*(expr+i)-'0';
  else{
    switch(sg){
     case '+': *result += number;
     break;
     case '-': *result -= number;
     break;
     case '*': *result *= number;
     break;
     case '/': if(number==0) return 0;
        *result /= number;
     break;
    }
     number = 0;
     sg = *(expr + i);
   }
  if (*(expr + i)=='\0') return 1;
  return calculate_rec(expr, result, i + 1, sg, number);
}
```

This program works good, but skips the first number in a given string, from string: 10+1+2/2 the result is 1.5 and should be 6.5.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior in standard C.

Comment: `*(expr + i)` can be written more simply and idiomatically as `expr[i]`

Comment: `*result += number;` - result is used uninitialized. When parsing the first number, you need to just set `*result = number`. You skip it and go immediately to `+ 2` doing `*result += number;`. Feel like you could pass another `, bool result_initialized` variable to your function and before the switch do `if (result_initialized == false) { result_initialized = true; *result = number } else switch (sq) {....`

Comment: There's no need for the `expr` and `res` variables. Your code would be clearer if you wrote `calculate(expression, &result);`. And as Kamil said, you need to initialize `result` to `0` in `main()`.

Comment: You're actually implementing a Reverse Polish calculator, since you use the operator to process the number before it, you don't process the numbers around the operator.

Comment: Note that calling `fflush` on an input-only stream (like `stdin)` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as *undefined behavior*. There's one implementation that adds it as a non-portable extension, so please don't use it.

Comment: The first time you find an operator (`+,-,*,/`), `sg` does not have a value, so the `switch` is skipped and `number` is reset to `0`. Twenty second solution: prepend "0+" to the input string. (And don't forget to initialize `float result=0;` as previously mentioned).

Comment: Use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` (or whatever options your compiler has to output warnings)  to detect some of these errors by yourself

Answer (score 0):

walk through the list recursively and perform the multiplication and division operations,
and replace the left hand value with zero the operator with plus and the right hand value with the value.  Then recursively move through the list again and carry out the addition and subtraction operations.

Comment: OP might find it hard to see the helpfulness of this answer, because what you describe is probably exactly what they tried to do. You could probably make the useful part more obvious by explaining more, maybe adding some code. Or highlight where exactly what OP coded is different from what you describe.

Comment: i forgot to add that the priority of operation is not important and do them one by one